# Proof Verification/Help of Euler-Phi function Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, proof-verification, ring-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to prove the following theorem, but I Feel like I am missing a bridge between my reasoning and the conclusion. *I posted this question and deleted it because someone edited it incorrectly (he/she put $a^{\phi(n)-1}-1$ instead of $a^{\phi(n)}-1$ and the answers were just corrections of the false edit*. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

**Theorem**: If $a$ is an integer coprime to $n$, then $a^{\phi(n)}-1$ is divisible by $n$, that is, $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$. ($\phi(n)$ is the Euler-Phi function)

**Proof**:

$\phi(n)<n$ is the number of numbers coprime to $n$ with $n\in N$

Those numbers form an abelian multiplicative group of order $\phi(n)\in N$

So $\forall{a\in G_{\phi(n)}}$ (the multiplicative group) we have $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$

Comment: You can start using that $n=p_1^{a_1}\times...\times p_k^{a_k}$ and then evaluate $\phi(n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globally, it's fine. A few notes:

1. Why did you write that $\phi(n)<1$? It happens that $\phi(1)=1$.
2. $\phi(n)$ is the number of *non-negative integers* less than $n$ and coprime with it.
3. There is no need to introduce the notation $G_{\phi(n)}$. You just state that you are working in the group of all non-negative integers smaller than $n$ and coprime with it. Since it has order $\phi(n)$, $a^{\phi(n)}$ is the identity element of that group. In other words, $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$.